# How do I stop MongoDB from sorting my data?

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to create a cards game but I am stuck at the point of returning cards with MongoDB: player has 30 cards, when clicking on a card the card does an animation with translate and rotate to reveal the value of the card , and since I only need to reveal the value of 3 cards, I need them to end up in the order in which they were chosen, but when I choose them, it returns them to me sorted by the value that the card has; so, for example, if I choose 1, 2, 3; no problem, but if I choose 2, 1, 3; it returns 1, 2, 3.

I've tried `sort()` and it doesn't work, because as I said I need it to return them in the chosen order, neither ascending nor descending (anyway it is sorting the cards without `sort`). I have tried with Express Handlebars, but apparently it creates an array, so when I put for example `cards.[0].number`; in the case of 2,1,3 it still returns 1 and not 2.
This is my code:

```
 router.post('/cards', (req, res) =>{
        let zahl1 = req.body.zahl1;
        let zahl2 = req.body.zahl2;
        let zahl3 = req.body.zahl3;
        cards.find({"zahl": {$in:[zahl1, zahl2, zahl3]}}, { _id: 0}, function(err, cards) {
       return res.render('cardsGame', {
                cards: cards
               });
        });
    });
```

Since I am having this issue I am working with a simple HTML to find out how to solve this issue:

```
  </form>
  <form method="post" action="/cards" id="bilden">
  <input type="text" id="hallo1" class="w-25">
  <input type="text" id="hallo2" class="w-25">
  <input type="text" id="hallo3" class="w-25">
  <a id="funktioniert" onclick="hinrichten()"><input type="submit" value="cards" class="btn btn-primary"></a>
  <input type="text" name="zahl1" id="zahl1" target="zahl1" class="w-25">
  <input type="text" name="zahl2" id="zahl2" target="zahl2" class="w-25">
  <input type="text" name="zahl3" id="zahl3" target="zahl3" class="w-25">
  </form>
  <script>
  let newTextInput1 = document.getElementById('hallo1');
  let newTextInput2 = document.getElementById('hallo2');
  let newTextInput3 = document.getElementById('hallo3');
  let newAncla = document.getElementById('funktioniert');
  let inputResult1 = document.getElementById('zahl1');
  let inputResult2 = document.getElementById('zahl2');
  let inputResult3 = document.getElementById('zahl3');

    function hinrichten(){
      inputResult1.value = newTextInput1.value;
      inputResult2.value = newTextInput2.value; 
      inputResult3.value = newTextInput3.value;  
    }
  </script>
```

Can someone help me find a way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: It's not immediately obvious (at least to me) what's happening here. Can you narrow the code down to what inserts the data and what is querying it?

Comment: What indexes are there on the cards collection?

Comment: @Joe, hi, the _id, the number (zahl) and an image(img). You gave me an idea, I will try to make the search by the _id to check if it is not changing the sort, and let you know. Thank you!

Comment: @Joe I tried with the _id, but since it is also sort ascending it is the same issue I have with the number.

Comment: @RQDQ Hi, thank you for answering, since I am stuck here it is easier to work with the code I just upload, three inputs where I write the numbers and try to get the result from the database, but if I write in the first input: 1, in the second 30 and in the third 21, instead of getting a result of 1, 30 and 21, I get 1, 21 and 30, they are being sort in ascending order without me requesting it, so I am trying to find out why is this happening and how to change it.  I hope I can clear your doubts. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

A single MongoDB node returns documents in the order they are encountered.  If an index is used to optimize the query, the documents will be encountered in the sorted order of the index.

If you need documents in the order they were inserted into the database, you could hint the [$natural](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/meta/natural/#-natural) index, but that would mean every such query would be a collection scan.

To get them in the order they appear in the request, you will need to sort them on the client side.

Perhaps something like:

```
router.post('/cards', (req, res) =>{
        let zahl1 = req.body.zahl1;
        let zahl2 = req.body.zahl2;
        let zahl3 = req.body.zahl3;
        let zahls = [zahl1, zahl2, zahl3];
        cards.find({"zahl": {$in:zahls}}, { _id: 0}, function(err, cards) {
            let cardsSort = cards.sort(function(a,b){
                               aidx = zahls.indexOf(a.zahl);
                               bidx = zahls.indexOf(b.zahl);
                               return (aidx - bidx);
                            });
            return res.render('cardsGame', {
                 cards: cardsSort
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: I just noticed a typo in my code.  The key is the database doesn't query for the first item in the array, and then the second, it will scan the index, or the collection, in order and return the documents in the order they are found.  If you want them in a different order, you have to sort.  Since the sort order is not clearly defined, it will need to be done in the client.

Comment: thank you for answering, but it didn't work.

Comment: bah, typos got me again.  Here's a demo of the sorting: https://jsfiddle.net/7y2uk38j/

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solve it:

```
router.post('/cards', (req, res) =>{
    let zahl1 = req.body.zahl1;
    let zahl2 = req.body.zahl2;
    let zahl3 = req.body.zahl3;
    let zahls = [zahl1, zahl2, zahl3];
     cards.find({"zahl": {$in:zahls}}, { _id: 0}, function(cards){
        let A = cards[0];
        let B = cards[1];
        let C = cards[2];

        function numerin(){
            if (zahl1 < zahl2 && zahl2 < zahl3 && zahl1 < zahl3) {
                zahl1 = A;
                zahl2 = B;
                zahl3 = C;
                return cards = [A,B,C];
            } else if (zahl1 < zahl2 && zahl1 < zahl3 && zahl3 < zahl2) {
                zahl1 = A;
                zahl2 = C;
                zahl3 = B;
                return cards = [A,C,B];
            } else if (zahl1 < zahl3 && zahl2 < zahl1 && zahl3 > zahl2) {
                zahl1 = B;
                zahl2 = A;
                zahl3 = C;
                return cards = [B,A,C];
            } else if (zahl1 > zahl3 && zahl3 > zahl2 && zahl1 > zahl2) {
                zahl1 = C;
                zahl2 = A;
                zahl3 = B;
                return cards = [C,A,B];
            } else if (zahl1 > zahl2 && zahl2 > zahl3 && zahl1 > zahl3) {
                zahl1 = C;
                zahl2 = B;
                zahl3 = A;
                return cards = [C,B,A];
            } else {
                zahl1 = B;
                zahl2 = C;
                zahl3 = A;
                return cards = [B,C,A];
            }
             };
        return res.render('cardsGame',{
        cards: numerin(),
                  })
                });
            
            });
```

When I got here, I had another problem if my numbers were 1,2,3 everything was ok, but if I had 5,10,25, the code was bringing 10,25,5 since it was just reading the first number, so to solve this in numbers from 1 to 9 I wrote 10 before (since mongoDB Compass didn't allowed me to add just a 0) an to all the other numbers I add just a 1 before, so instead of having numbers from 1 to 30 I have numbers from 101 to 130.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).