# How do I return data from an aggregation of MongoDB with NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, aggregate, mongoose-schema

I am trying to create a cards game but I am stuck at the point of returning cards with MongoDB: player has 30 cards, when clicking on a card the card does an animation with translate and rotate to reveal the value of the card , and since I only need to reveal the value of 3 cards, I need them to end up in the order in which they were chosen, but when I choose them, it returns them to me sorted by the value that the card has; so, for example, if I choose 1, 2, 3; no problem, but if I choose 2, 1, 3; it returns 1, 2, 3 (to solve all this I am working with three inputs and a button to return data, simple HTML and JavaScript, until I can get the data I want it is easier than be playing the cards all the time).

I found the following code that allows me to keep the order entered, the problem is that when I used `$find`, it did not return the data in the order I wanted, but it did return the data, now I use `$aggregate` and it only returns an array with the numbers entered (in the order I want them), but it does not bring me data from the database, how do I get it to return the data with `$aggregate`?
This is the code with `$aggregate` that is not working:

```
 router.post('/cards', (req, res) =>{
        let zahl1 = req.body.zahl1;
        let zahl2 = req.body.zahl2;
        let zahl3 = req.body.zahl3;
        let zahls = [zahl1, zahl2, zahl3];
        let m = { "$match" : { "zahl" : { "$in" : zahls } } };
        let a = { "$addFields" : { "__order" : { "$indexOfArray" : [ zahls, "$zahl" ] } } };
        let s = { "$sort" : { "__order" : 1 } };
        cards.aggregate( [ m, a, s] , { _id: 0}, function(cards){
                return res.json({
                    success: true,  
                    cards: cards,
                    zahls: zahls
                })
            });
})
```

The code with `$find`:

```
cards.find({"zahl": {$in:zahls}}, { _id: 0}, function(cards){
            return res.json({
                    success: true,  
                    cards: cards,
                    zahls: zahls
                      })
                    });
```

So, for example I take 3 cards: `"zahl1"=30`, `"zahl2"=5`, `"zahl3"=25`.

With `aggregate` I get this result:

`{"success":true,"cards":[],"zahls":["30","5","25"]}`

and with `find` I get this result:

`{"success":true,"cards":[{"number":"5","name":"Monkey", "age":"9 Years Old","home":"Jungle","zahl":5},{"number":"25","name":"Lion","age":"2 Years Old","home":"Jungle","zahl":25},{"number":"30","name":"Shark","age":"5 Years Old","home":"Ocean","zahl":30}],"zahls":["30","5","25"]}`.

But I am trying to get this result:

`{"success":true,"cards":[{"number":"30","name":"Shark","age":"5 Years Old","home":"Ocean","zahl":30},{"number":"5","name":"Monkey", "age":"9 Years Old","home":"Jungle","zahl":5},{"number":"25","name":"Lion","age":"2 Years Old","home":"Jungle","zahl":25}],"zahls":["30","5","25"]}`

I've also tried with `.exec({})` but I still have the same issue.
Can someone help me find a way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: `$addFields` and `$indexOfArray` are not available via `find`, does `aggregate` not work?

Comment: Hi Joe, I know. What is not working is the `aggregate` with the `res.json`/`res.render` (I get an array of numbers). The `find` with the `res.json` does (I get the data but not in the order I want).

Comment: Aren't callbacks in mongoose usually `function (err, results)`?

Comment: I tried with `err`, but it is not returning an error, it is returning an array.  This is the answer I am getting: {"success":true,"zahls":["85","49","92"]}, even if numbers are from 1 to 30.

Comment: The sample aggregation you should should be returning a list of documents, can you provide a self-contained example that demonstrates getting that return?  Also in the post path, the return looks like it should have the fieldname `cards` not `zahls`, where is that return actually coming from?

Comment: Also the aggregate call expected the second parameter to be a options object, what you have there looks like a projection.  Try moving that to a $project stage in the pipeline.

Comment: Joe, I gave an example, I hope it helps clarify what I need. And you was right since I've been trying to find out what was going on, I copied the last code I had and forgot the fieldname `cards`. I will try what you've said about the $project stage.

Comment: that aggregation looks right. Try not re-using the variable name 'cards'

Comment: Since I wasn't able to find out the `aggregate` issue, I solve it with `find` this way: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/75526102/20847673]